# How to display Metaplex NFT in React using @metaplex/js and programs.metadata.Metadata

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solana, nft, metaplex

I am trying to run this 'getting started' example from the docs. However I think there's been a change and programs.metadata.Metadata (shown there) no longer works.

https://docs.metaplex.com/sdk/js/getting-started

They suggest this:

```
import { Connection, programs } from '@metaplex/js';

const connection = new Connection('devnet');
const tokenPublicKey = 'Gz3vYbpsB2agTsAwedtvtTkQ1CG9vsioqLW3r9ecNpvZ';

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const ownedMetadata = await programs.metadata.Metadata.load(connection, tokenPublicKey);
    console.log(ownedMetadata);
  } catch {
    console.log('Failed to fetch metadata');
  }
};

run();
```

I have this in my React app:

```
import { Connection, programs } from '@metaplex/js';

const connection = new Connection('devnet');
const tokenPublicKey = 'Gz3vYbpsB2agTsAwedtvtTkQ1CG9vsioqLW3r9ecNpvZ';

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const ownedMetadata = await programs.metadata.Metadata.load(connection, tokenPublicKey);
    console.log(ownedMetadata);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('Failed to fetch metadata');
    console.log(error);
  }
};

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p onClick={run}>would be cool if it worked</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I get an error as though programs.metadata.Metadata doesn't exist - "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Metadata')". I even took this out of React and did a plain node script to just run the example code, which fails in the same way.

Any idea on how I could fix this?

Comment: Try `import { Metadata } from'@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'` instead?

Comment: Thank you! That solved it.

Answer (score 3):

For users that find this question via search:
There is now a better solution than using `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` directly. Have a look at [@metaplex/js-next findByMint](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js-next#findByMint)

Those lines should be all you need. `imageUrl` would be the image path.

```
import { Metaplex } from "@metaplex-foundation/js-next";
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
const mint = new PublicKey("ATe3DymKZadrUoqAMn7HSpraxE4gB88uo1L9zLGmzJeL");
const nft = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint(mint);
const imageUrl = nft.metadata.image;
```